# Vectorization or alternative to speed up MATLAB loop

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I am using MATLAB to run a for loop in which variable-length portions of a large vector are updated at each iteration with the content of another vector; something like:

```
for k=1:N
   vec1(idx_start1(k):idx_end1(k)) = vec1(idx_start1(k):idx_end1(k)) +...
        a(k)*vec2(idx_start2(k):idx_end2(k));
end
```

The selected portions of `vec1` and `vec2` are not so small and `N` can be quite large; moreover, if this can be useful, `idx_end(k)<idx_start(k+1)` does not necessarily hold (i.e. `vec1`'s edited portions may be partially re-updated in subsequent iterations). As a consequence, the above is by far the slowest portion of code in my script and I would like to speed it up, if possible.

Is there any way to vectorize the above for loop in order to make it run faster? Or, are there any alternative approaches to improve its execution speed?

EDIT:

As requested in the comments, here are some example values: Using the profiler to check execution times, the loop above runs in about 3.3 s with `N=5e4`, `length(vec1)=3e6`, `length(vec2)=1.7e3` and the portions indexed by `idx_start/end` are slightly shorter on average than the latter, although not significantly.

Of course, 3.3 s is not particularly worrying in itself, but I would like to be able to increase especially `N` and `vec1` by 1 or 2 orders of magnitude and in such a loop it will take quite longer to run.

Comment: You can probably rewrite this as a matrix product. Depending on the relative sizes of N and the vector, this could speed up or slow down the code... Creating the matrix to multiply by might involve a similar loop though. Not sure. Please post some example data (e.g. using random values), what matters most is that the sizes of your example match your practical problem, as with different sizes there are different optimal solutions.

Comment: If this is really time critical, you could implement this in C/C++ and call it using mex. This looks pretty straight-forward to vectorize.

Comment: if I understand your question and the values of vec1 depend on previous values of vec1 in the loop there is causality so parallelization is not an option.

Comment: @dpdp Exactly, it can't be parallelized.

Comment: @dpdp There is potential to parallelize if the index vectors can be separated into sets which only modify the parts of `vec1` each (e.g., just one quarter each) -- possibly splitting some regions into two parts. This would only be useful if that preparation does not take more time than is saved, of course ...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I couldn't find a way to speed up your code.  This is the code I created to try to speed it up:

```
N = 5e4;
vec1 = 1:3e6;
vec2 = 1:1.7e3;
rng(0)
a = randn(N, 1);
idx_start1 = randi([1, 2.9e6], N, 1);
idx_end1 = idx_start1 + 1000;
idx_start2 = randi([1, 0.6e3], N, 1);
idx_end2 = idx_start2 + 1000;
for k=1:N
   vec1(idx_start1(k):idx_end1(k)) = vec1(idx_start1(k):idx_end1(k)) + a(k) * vec2(idx_start2(k):idx_end2(k));
%    use = idx_start1(k):idx_end1(k);
%    vec1(use) = vec1(use) + a(k) * vec2(idx_start2(k):idx_end2(k));
end
```

The two commented-out lines of code in the for loop were my attempt to speed it up, but it actually made it slower, much to my surprise.  Generally, I would create a variable for an array that is used more than once thinking that is faster, but it is not.  The code that is not commented out runs in 0.24 s versus 0.67 seconds for the code that is commented out.

Comment: I would be surprised if the commented attempt would have been faster. Matlab likely detects constructs such as `vec1(i1:i2)`, whereas if you do `vec1(use)`, it will have to actually read the `use` vector.